# Где указано на перевод поста в базе данных WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Мне необходимо перенести посты со старой базы данных (не WP) в базу данных WP. На сайте используется  PolyLang.
Следовательно вопрос по WordPress:
Где в базе данных я могу увидеть указание на принадлежность поста к определенному языку или что-то еще, что мне поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Polylang используется стандартная структура как для меток и рубрик - таксономия, термы, посты, свзять постов и термов.

- Таксономия `language` лежит в таблице `wp_term_taxonomy`
- Конкретные языки в таблице `wp_terms`
- Связь такосномии с термами в таблице `wp_term_taxonomy`
- Привязка записи к языку в таблице `wp_term_relationships`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Можешь подсказать что такое slug в таблице wp_terms. Насколько я прочитал это типа как урл, но у меня slug для поста pll_5d51a1717ae20 и это никак не связано с постом.

Comment: Это слаг (последняя часть URL) термина в таксономии.